Dart code suggestion is not working while typing in Intellij IDE
While coding in Intellij IDE for dart, it's not showing suggestion. But Initially, the code was suggested, suddenly nothing was suggested. As shown in picture. Also I set the dart sdk path in intellij ide firstly:
Here an example of no auto-complete happening:

How can I overcome this problem?

If you open your pubspec.yaml, in Intellij, do you see a panel where you can click e.g. "pub upgrade"?

Yes, I have seen a panel where 'pub get' , 'pub upgrade', 'pub outdated' etc are available.  Should I click on pub upgrade?

You can try and see if it makes thing work. My question was more to check if you had the Dart plugin installed correctly. But you should run at least pub get in your repository at least once to make sure dependencies are fetched and the project links correctly to everything.
